# Nested JPanels and GridBagLayout Not "Packing" Components

Tags: java, swing, awt, gridbaglayout

I've attached a screenshot for which the following `Border` legend applies:

Yellow = `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`

Blue = `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout`

Fuchsia = `JPanel` with `FlowLayout`

There are two panels not blocked out in colors that warrant mentioning:

1)  The title panel where the word "Primary" is displayed; this panel is at `BorderLayout.NORTH` in "Yellow" panel.

2)  The image panel where the image of the device is located; this panel is a sibling to "Fuchsia"

[image: Nested Layout Problem]

"Blue" is at `BorderLayout.CENTER` in "Yellow" while "Fuchsia" and the image panel are given the following constraints:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

//"Blue".add(imagePanel, c);

c.weighty = 0.80;       
c.gridy = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


//"Blue".add("Fuchsia", c);
```

As you can probably tell from the image, I'm trying to get rid of the "wasted" space in "Blue" right below "Fuchsia".  I don't seem to be able to do it with `GridBagConstraints`, so am I just using the wrong `LayoutManager`?  It looks to me like "Blue", who is at `CENTER` in the `BorderLayout` is just giving each child `JPanel` half of the available space and reserving the remainder space instead of contracting upward.  What am I missing here?  Is this simply a matter of setting a preferred or maximum size on "Fuchsia"?  it doesn't seem like that will get me where I want to be, since the border around "Fuchsia" (which is covered by my color coding) is where I want the end of the component to be.

Comment: Had you tried using `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH/c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;`, instead of `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` ? Or had you explicitly defined any sizes for `JFrame/JPanel` anywhere inside your code ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw There are no explicit size definitions in the code.  I will try the `fill` suggestions shortly.

Comment: I think it is the layout manager of the parent of your yellow `JFrame`. Which one is it? My [test code](http://pastebin.com/PeM98u1t) shows the desired behavior. Do you mind posting a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: @Howard The parent of "Yellow" is yet another `JPanel` but with a `null` (Absolute?) layout.  I know that's blasphemy, but in my inexperience I don't know of any other way to accomplish drag-able entities ("Yellow" and all like panels).  They're user-moveable and display connection lines between them.  Interestingly, if I explicitly `setBounds()` on "Yellow" and provide a smaller size, "Fuchsia" and the image panel begin to overlap, with the "wasted" space still below "Fuchsia".  Maybe the problem is in "Blue"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: LAYOUT SNAPSHOT]

Have a look at this output, from this code example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutTest
{
    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JLabel headingLabel = new JLabel("Primary");
        topPanel.add(headingLabel);
        contentPane.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();   
        JLabel imageLabel = null;
        try
        {
            imageLabel = new JLabel(
                            new ImageIcon(
                                new java.net.URL(
                                    "http://pscode.org/"
                                    + "tame/screenshot/"
                                    + "landscape/slider1.gif")));
        }
        catch(Exception e)  
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imagePanel.add(imageLabel);
        centerPanel.add(imagePanel, gbc);

        JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
        detailsPanel.setOpaque(true);
        detailsPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        detailsPanel.setBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                              5, 5, 5, 5));
        detailsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

        JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Chassis Status : ");
        JLabel usageLabel = new JLabel("Bandwidth Usage : ");
        JLabel fanLabel = new JLabel("Fan Status : ");

        detailsPanel.add(statusLabel);
        detailsPanel.add(usageLabel);
        detailsPanel.add(fanLabel);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weighty = 0.8;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        centerPanel.add(detailsPanel, gbc);

        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new LayoutTest().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks extremely promising.  I just ran the code here and wasn't sure it fit the bill, since the panel with the three JLabels looked similarly sized, but after removing two of them I can clearly see that the sizing is working correctly.  Will update in a moment.

Comment: Ahha, seems to me the only problem in your code is as mentioned by me, in the comment, instead of using HORIZONTAL, you can only use BOTH, that way no space will be left out, in any direction. Though you can comment out `gbc.gridheight = 3;` this line from my code, then it works very much as expected by you :-)

Comment: +1 good one, but I'm by default tried to avoids GBC on forums :-)

Answer (score 4):

Without using GridBagLayout could be

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class NestedLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel yellowNorthPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel yellowPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel fuchsiaTopPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel fuchsiaBottonPanel = new JPanel();

    public NestedLayout() {
        yellowNorthPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 5));
        yellowPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        yellowPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 5));
        bluePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        bluePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 5));
        fuchsiaTopPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.cyan, 5));
        fuchsiaBottonPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.cyan, 5));
        bluePanel.add(fuchsiaTopPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        bluePanel.add(fuchsiaBottonPanel);
        yellowPanel.add(bluePanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(yellowNorthPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(yellowPanel);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NestedLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's basically what's happening now, I think.  I really do want the Fuchsia `JPanel` to be smaller (for now) than the image panel, and potentially expand it to be larger as more information needs to be displayed there.

Comment: there coud be one your small mistake, `fuchsiaTopPanel` can pretty accepting size that came form its `JComponent` by calling (uncomment `pack()`) or by setting (last property) `PreferredSize`, I think that there no issue with proper sizing on the screen in this case